# Flutter : Based on user settings show or hide notification UI

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

The user can enable or disable to see push notifications, if the user has disabled the notification, the push notification should be received but not shown to the user, and i would like to save the notification detail in db. i'm using FCM in flutter, Can this be achieved? TIA

Comment: https://dev.to/arthurdenner/save-data-from-push-notifications-to-sqlite-2pm2 Have a look

Comment: Yes, thats about saving the notification to SQL lite, how about not displaying the notification to User, if user has turned off not to see notification.

Comment: use push notification local